Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value Color
I have a data class for some data:
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class ChartModel(
    val value: Float,
    val color: @RawValue Color
): Parcelable

The usage looks in Jetpack Compose like this:
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.*

...

val chartModel = ChartModel(13.0f, Color(0xFF3EB489))

...

and at some point once that class is called there occurs an Exception:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value Color(0.24313726, 0.7058824, 0.5372549, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1946)
       at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Slice.writeToParcel(PieChart.kt:17)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1965)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1871)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1153)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1893)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1153)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1893)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:1004)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:986)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1858)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:1004)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:986)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1858)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1153)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1893)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1036)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
       at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1304)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1105)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1862)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:1036)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
       at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1304)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1105)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1862)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.dumpStats(BaseBundle.java:1690)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.dumpStats(BaseBundle.java:1727)
       at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:150)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

I don't know if the app crashes when that exception occurs since I get this in Crashlytics.
I googled and couldn't find any solution for this case.
Why does it occur and how can I fix it?

It seems like Color is not a supported type for the @Parcelize annotation. You can view the supported types in the documentation. You probably already got a warning indicating that you should annotate the Color type with @RawValue, but that only satisfies the compiler, while it does not guarantee that the serialization will work at runtime.
This is also indicated by the RawValue javadoc:
/**
 * Write the corresponding property value with [android.os.Parcel.writeValue].
 * Serialization may fail at runtime, depending on actual property value type.
 */
@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class RawValue

So you would either have to write your own Parceler, or instead of storing a Color, store the color code as Int as suggested here:
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class ChartModel(
    val value: Float,
    val color: Int
): Parcelable

You can use it in your Composable like this:
val chartModel = ChartModel(13.0f, (0xFF3EB489).toInt() )

Text(text = "Hello World", color = Color(chartModel.color))

